# Atualizar dados de formulário PHP

Tags: php

Gostaria de ajuda para resolver o seguinte problema, na parte de edição de um formulário tenho campos que são criados como "rows" desde a parte de cadastro, o cadastro está correto, porém, na edição não estou conseguindo inserir as mudanças nas respectivas linhas (creio que se aplique com algo como uma matriz).

[image: Imagem Exemplo]

Parte da ação de salvar

```
    $regioes_nm = $_POST['nome_regiao'];
    $regioes_cd = $_POST['code_regiao'];

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($regioes_nm); $i++) {

        $cd = $regioes_cd[$i];

        // Grava Região
        $nome_reg = $regioes_nm[$i];        
        $idRegiao = $conexao->consulta("UPDATE proprietario_regiao SET "
                                . " nome = '$nome_reg',"
                                . " data_cadastro = 'CURDATE()'"
                                . "WHERE $bd_ID = '$id'");

        // Grava Gerente
        $nome_ger = $_POST["nome".$cd."_ger"];
        $telefone_ger = $_POST["telefone".$cd."_ger"];
        $email_ger = $_POST["email".$cd."_ger"];
        $senha_ger = $_POST["senha1".$cd."_ger"];
        $ID_Inserido = $conexao->consulta("UPDATE proprietario_gerente SET "
                                ." idRegiao = $idRegiao,"
                                ." nome = '$nome_ger',"
                                ." telefone = '$telefone_ger',"
                                ." email = '$email_ger',"
                                ." senha = '".base64_encode($senha_ger)."',"
                                ." data_cadastro = 'CURDATE()'"
                                ."WHERE $bd_ID = '$id'"); 

        // Grava Técnico
        $nome_tec = $_POST["nome".$cd."_tec"];
        $telefone_tec = $_POST["telefone".$cd."_tec"];
        $email_tec = $_POST["email".$cd."_tec"];
        $senha_tec = $_POST["senha1".$cd."_tec"];
        for ($j = 0; $j < count($nome_tec); $j++) {
            $ID_Inserido = $conexao->consulta("UPDATE proprietario_tecnico SET "
                                ." idRegiao = $idRegiao,"
                                ." nome = '$nome_tec[$j]',"
                                ." telefone = '$telefone_tec[$j]',"
                                ." email = '$email_tec[$j]',"
                                ." senha = '".base64_encode($senha_tec[$j])."',"
                                ." data_cadastro = 'CURDATE()'"
                                ."WHERE $bd_ID = '$id'");  
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Eu não entendi como você está editando no formulário. Entendi que você está listando os usuários linha por linha, e seus dados em campos input editáveis. mas qual o link de submit pra fazer o update?

Comment: É exatamente isso, bom os links são esses:  `<button type="submit" class="action-bullet" value="" name="Sair"><div class="action-save-quit"></div><span><?=TXT_BOTAO_EDITAR_E_SAIR?></span></button>` 
 `<button type="submit" class="action-bullet" value=""><div class="action-save"></div><span><?=TXT_BOTAO_EDITAR?></span></button>`

Comment: Mas o botão está no print?
Apresenta algum erro?
de ante mão já recomendo ver se um ajax resolve seu problema.

Comment: Não, não está no print, o que eu retorno é isto:  

 $conexao->desconectar ();

 $_SESSION['msg'] = "ok|".TXT_ACAO_RETORNO_EDICAO;
 if ($_POST['opgrava']=='Sair') {
  header("Location: ../../../home.php?area=".$sis_Nome_mP."_gerenciar");
 } else {
  header("Location: ../../../home.php?area=".$sis_Nome_mP."_editar&id=$id");
 }

 die();

Comment: Com ajax eu poderia utilizar o que?

Comment: Aliás mais fácil qeu usar ajax é criar um form em cada linha e o botão de submit enviaria os dados para a página de update.